# How can I determine which ancillary file[s] is/are missing?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, networking

If I right-click my app from a network drive and select Run As | Current User, whether the app runs depends on whether I click the sub-checkbox ("Protect my computer and data from unauthorized program activity").

If I do select the "Protect my computer..." checkbox and then select the OK button, I get, "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application."

However, if I uncheck that checkbox, it runs fine.

So apparently the .NET runtime is considered "unauthorized program activity."

If I run this app from the same place (a folder on a mapped drive that is neither mine nor the user's C: drive) from another user's machine, it won't start up at all, and gives me an iofileloadexception error. But AFAIK, the .DLLs the app needs have been copied over to the mapped drive's folder, as well as the text file the startup process references. Is there a tool that shows what ancillary files need to be distributed with a C# .exe created with Visual Studio (2010)? IOW, such a tool should tell me that I need the log4net.dll, a custom internal framework .DLL, and the aforementioned text file. And perhaps something else that, when deployed, would allow the app to run on the user's machine.

### UPDATED

Okay, I think I may be "on the trail" as far as being able to determine what files need to be deployed with a given .exe:

If you select Project |  Properties | Publish | Application Files in Visual 
Studio, it seems to show you just which files you need to deploy with your app. However, 
there are still a couple of issues (noted in parenthesis below; and the bombshell at the 
end):

```
EXE and related files:

1) <appName>.exe (duh, AKA "doh")
2) <appName>.exe.config
3) <appName>.exe.manifest (I have no such file - although I do have a file named
<appName>.vshost.exe.manifest; should I rename it by stripping out the "vshost" part of the name?)
4) <appName>.ico

DLLs:

Any non-native DLLs your project uses, such as (in this case):

<customFrameworkAssembly>.dll
log4net.dll
Devart.Data.dll
Devart.Data.Oracle.dll
```

HOWEVER, it does not explain why I'm able to run the app from another developer's 
machine (even when those files had not been deployed to the shared network directory).

Comment: What version of .net is your app running on?

Comment: Is this a question or a complaint?

Comment: @John: it targets .NET 4; the user does have that (and earlier) versions of .NET installed.

Comment: Can you provide the details of that `FileLoadException`? The remote app you're trying to execute will run on your local machine, with your local copy of the .NET runtime, which might not be the one it's expecting to find. And yes, loading the local .NET runtime from a remote app is unauthorized by default when you choose `Protect my computer`, as it should be.

Comment: It runs on another machine from that mapped drive/folder just fine - one that was set up for a developer who is no longer here. Could it be relying on something that is installed with Visual Studio (something developers, but not "the common rabble" would have)?

Comment: @Frederic: The "Error Report Contents" dialog that can be invoked from the user's machine following the app crashing contains a plethora of arcane information, such as hexadecimal representations of Code, Flags, Record, Address, System Info, etc., but nothing that looks like it's of any real value to me. When the err msg is "io file load exception," you would think the first thing reported would be what it was trying but unable to load. That would be the most helpful info to me.

Comment: @Clay, this is not good, according to your comment it looks like you're crashing the CLR, which should not happen under normal circumstances. Can you take a screenshot of that arcane information and add it to your question? Also, regarding your previous comment, developers' machines usually have all kind of libraries installed because of our very job, so you should identify the prerequisites necessary for the app to work that will not present on a typical machine, and package them with your app.

Comment: @Frederic: Yes, I agree, I should - but how? There must be some tool that tells you just what prerequisites your app has. For example, we do use devArt dotConnect for Oracle components. I assume these are compiled into the .exe, but if not, how do I know for sure (which .DLLs to deploy)?

Comment: @Frederic: I don't know how to add a screenshot to my question (or if I have the rights to do so), but I will post to a separate blog and then add the link at the bottom of the original question.

Comment: @Clay, or you could post a link to an image hosted somewhere else, anyway's fine :)

Comment: @Frederic: Here they are: http://warbler.posterous.com/screen-shots-after-app-fails-to-start There are even more arcane bits (no pun intended) of info after these six screens (things only a bit-flipper/assembler savant could possibly grok).

Comment: Check the event log on the machine that had the failure. There should be an error entry in the Application section with more (but not much more) understandable information about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files that you need to deploy can be seen from the project in Visual Studio by selecting Project |  Properties | Publish | Application files…

Once you move these to the same location as the .exe, all is right with the world again (well, this little part of your little world, anyway).